# Solving definite integral without using sec and cosh.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Having troubles with defining intervals

[image]

Comment: I think there is a mistake Because: $x=2sect$ and $$dx=2sect.tantdt=\frac{2sint}{cos^2t}dt$$  not$$\frac{2sint}{cost}dt$$

Comment: Yes. It's \cos^2 t  .

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way without the use of $\sec$ or $\cosh$.

Ensure $x>2$. Now write $\sqrt{x^2-4}=(x-2)t$.

Note that we have $t>1$. Solving for $x$  we have $x=\frac{2(t^2+1)}{t^2-1}\implies\mathrm{d}x=-\frac{8t}{(t^2-1)^2}\,\mathrm{d}t$. This transforms the integrand to a rational function of $t$:

$$\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x=-\int\frac{16t^2}{(t^2+1)(t^2-1)^2}\,\mathrm{d}t.$$

Expanding via partial fractions,

$$-\frac{16t^2}{(t^2+1)(t^2-1)^2}=\frac{4}{t^2+1}-\frac{2}{(t-1)^2}-\frac{2}{(t+1)^2}.$$

Hence, the integral has been reduced to three elementary integrals, and then the only job for you is to remember to change limits and evaluate the integrals.

Comment: I tried to solve this integral using cos and sin and it did't work. Your solution is way more intresting. Thank you for help.

Comment: could you please explain why \sqrt {x^2 - 4} = (x-2)t ?

Comment: That is my choice of substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way with a little trick having in mind that

- $\left(\sqrt{x^2-4}\right)' = \frac x{\sqrt{x^2-4}}$

We have 
$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}x = \frac{x^2-4}{x\sqrt{x^2-4}}= \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-4}}-\frac{4}{x\sqrt{x^2-4}}$$

So, basically we only need the integral $\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-4}}$ which can be transformed using $u^2+4=x^2$ into
$$\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-4}}=\int \frac{du}{u^2+4}$$ 
$$=\frac 12\arctan\frac u2 (+C) = \frac 12\arctan\frac {\sqrt{x^2-4}}2 (+C)$$

So, we get

$$\int_2^4 \frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}x dx= \left[\sqrt{x^2-4}-2\arctan \frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2}\right]_2^4 = 2\sqrt 3 - \frac {2\pi}3$$

Answer (score 0):

With the substitution you considered the integral becomes
$\int_2^4\sqrt{1-(2/x)^2}dx=\int_2^42tan^2tdt=\int_2^42(sec^2t-1)dt.$
Now you can proceed with the answer!
There seems to be error in your expression for dx in terms of t.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of differential binom:

$$
\int x^m(a + bx^n)^pdx.
$$

In the following three cases, the integral can be expressed in elementary functions:

- $p$ is integers $\Rightarrow$ $x = t^k$, where $k$ is a common denominator of $m$ and $n$.
- $\frac{m+1}{n}$ is integer $\Rightarrow$ $a + bx^n = t^s$, where $s$ is the denominator of $p$.
- $p + \frac{m+1}{n}$ is integer $\Rightarrow$ $ax^{-n} + b = t^s$, where $s$ is the denominator of $p$.

In our example,

$$
\int_2^4 \frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x}dx = \int_2^4 x^{-1}(-4 + x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}dx,
$$

- $m = -1$
- $n = 2$
- $p = -\frac{1}{2}$
- $a = -4$
- $b = 1$

Now, we have

- $p = -\frac{1}{2}$ is NOT integer.
- $\frac{m+1}{n} = \frac{-1 + 1}{2} = 0$ is integer $\Rightarrow$ $-4 + x^2 = t^2$ (here, s = 2 is the denominator of $p$).
- $p + \frac{m+1}{n} = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{-1+1}{2} = -\frac{1}{2}$ is NOT integer.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_2^4 \frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x}dx &= \int_2^4 x^{-1}(-4 + x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}dx = \\ \\
 -4 + x^2 = t^2 &\Leftrightarrow xdx = tdt \\
 x = 2 &\Leftrightarrow t = 0 \\
 x = 4 &\Leftrightarrow t = \sqrt{12} = 2\sqrt{3} \\
&\Downarrow \\ \\
= \int_2^4 \frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x^2}xdx &= \int_0^{2\sqrt{3}} \frac{t}{t^2+4}tdt = \\
= \int_0^{2\sqrt{3}} \frac{t^2+4-4}{t^2+4}dt &= \int_0^{2\sqrt{3}} (1 - 4\frac{1}{t^2+4})dt = \\
= \int_0^{2\sqrt{3}}dt - 4\int_0^{2\sqrt{3}}\frac{1}{t^2+4}dt &= t|_0^{2\sqrt{3}} - 4 \frac{1}{2}\arctan(x/2)|_0^{2\sqrt{3}}= \\
= 2\sqrt{3}-2\arctan(\sqrt{3}) &= 2\sqrt{3}-\frac{2\pi}{3}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sqrt{x^2-4}=t$, so that $x=\sqrt{t^2+4}$ and $dx=\dfrac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+4}}$. Now

$$\int_2^4\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x}dx=\int_0^{2\sqrt{3}}\frac{t^2}{{t^2+4}}dt=2\sqrt3-2\arctan\sqrt3.$$

As the final answer involves $\pi$, you can't avoid the use of a trigonometric function.

Comment: How did you get 2sqrt3?

Comment: @LeanaK.: this is $\sqrt{12}$.